# How could I auto populate values on a website and execute without any help from the owner of said website

Tags: .net, web-applications

I have this time clock that I have to punch in and out of at work. I would like to write a simple application to populate the loggin, select the appropriate in/out radio button and submit.

I would like to begin this project but I'm unsure about where to start. Could someone point me in the right direction?

The specific site that I need to program against is the following (not sure if this helps)
https://www.payrollservers.us/sc/clock/webclock.asp

To clarify: I want to make an application to sign in and out without actually ever going to the website. Basically, I want to automate the entire process with a button or two.

Comment: If you don't want to do it by code, I would vote to move it to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 1):

Use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net). It's a programmatic web browser: with Java code, you tell it to go to the URL, find the form with a given ID or name (for example), fill in the text input field "A" with "foo", submit the form by clicking the "Log in" button, etc. Its [Get Started](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) page has useful examples.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to autofill some values on a specific form, you can write a [userscript](http://userscripts.org/) for the browser of your preference. I can't say much more without you clarifying your question.

Without going to the site, you can write a simple script **that does an HTTP POST to the form**.
Such script or program can be written in variety of languages, including but not limited to Python, Ruby, C#, etc.

Comment: I would like to autofill the values and submit without ever physically going to the site.

Comment: Do you know any programming languages?

Comment: Well, you can write a simple app in C# then. Do you have problem with anything in particular? This is not a discussion forum. Try to start, if you got a problem, come back and ask a specific question.